# If $f$ is an arithmetic function with $f(1)=1$ then $f$ is multiplicative

Tags: arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

I'm studying analytic number theory for undergraduates and I read this theorem in Tom Apostol's book on the second chapter:

> *Theorem 2.12.* If $f$ is multiplicative then $f(1)=1$

And under need there is a note that says that $\Lambda (n)$ is not multiplicative because $\Lambda (1) = 0$.
So I wonder if the converse of the theorem is true.

Comment: You mean $\Lambda(1)=0,$ I think.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it. Thanks @salpatz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arithmetic function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x = 1 \\
2 & x > 1\end{cases}
$$
is not multiplicative even though $f(1)=1$.

(But when the book says that $\Lambda(n)$ is not multiplicative because $\Lambda(1)=0$, it's using the contrapositive, not the converse...)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=2x-1$.  $f(1)=1$ but $f(6)=11 \neq f(2)\cdot f(3)=3\cdot 5=15$